# Including libcurl in project

Tags: c++, libcurl

So I downloaded the zip file from the curl website. I copied the directory with all of the header files into my include directory. Including the curl.h works with no problems, however, when I go to actually call a function, suddenly my c++ app will no longer compile.

Here's the error I'm receiving:

```
 [Linker error] undefined reference to
 `curl_easy_init'
```

Here's the code:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
      string url = "http://www.google.com";
      cout << "Retrieving " << url << endl;

      // Our curl objects
      CURL *curl;
      CURLcode result;

      // Create our curl handle  
      curl = curl_easy_init();  

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine if I comment out the curl=curl_easy_init() line.

According to the documentation this should work, [as seen here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html).

Any ideas?

Comment: Post the error you get.  Most likely this is a linking problem...

Comment: Edited...can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Post your command line args for linker. You probably forgot to tell linker you need curl. It can't guess which of the hundreds available libraries contains the symbols you need.

Comment: I'm not doing anything in command line, this is compiling/running on windows.

Comment: Then you should have a place in project options to add libraries. Did you add curl?

Answer (score 5):

you must link your program with the curl library

```
-L/path/of/curl/lib/libcurl.a (g++)
```

or add curl in your solution

```
Solution->properties->Link(ing) and add libcurl.lib
```

Comment: No. There's libcurl.imp, .plist, .rc and .vcproj, but no .a or .so

Comment: have you compiled it ?
./configure
make
make install
or have you built it with Visual studio ?

Comment: No, I was under the impression I could include the headers and it would just work from there?

Answer (score 1):

In `..\src\curl-7.71.1\winbuild` you can find "BUILD.WINDOWS.txt". In this text file they explain how to compile the lib.

```
Building with Visual C++, prerequisites
=======================================

   This document describes how to compile, build and install curl and libcurl
   from sources using the Visual C++ build tool. To build with VC++, you will
   of course have to first install VC++. The minimum required version of
   VC is 6 (part of Visual Studio 6). However using a more recent version is
   strongly recommended.

   VC++ is also part of the Windows Platform SDK. You do not have to install
   the full Visual Studio or Visual C++ if all you want is to build curl.

   The latest Platform SDK can be downloaded freely from:

    https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

   If you are building with VC6 then you will also need the February 2003
   Edition of the Platform SDK which can be downloaded from:

    https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12261

   If you wish to support zlib, openssl, c-ares, ssh2, you will have to download
   them separately and copy them to the deps directory as shown below:

   somedirectory\
    |_curl-src
    | |_winbuild
    |
    |_deps
      |_ lib
      |_ include
      |_ bin

   It is also possible to create the deps directory in some other random
   places and tell the Makefile its location using the WITH_DEVEL option.

Building straight from git
==========================

 When you check out code git and build it, as opposed from a released source
 code archive, you need to first run the "buildconf.bat" batch file (present
 in the source code root directory) to set things up.

Building with Visual C++
========================

Open a Visual Studio Command prompt:

     Using the 'Developer Command Prompt for VS <version>' menu entry:
       where version is the Visual Studio version. The developer prompt at default
       uses the x86 mode. It is required to call Vcvarsall.bat to setup the prompt
       for the machine type you want, using Vcvarsall.bat.
       This type of command prompt may not exist in all Visual Studio versions.

       For more information, check:
         https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs
         https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-enable-a-64-bit-visual-cpp-toolset-on-the-command-line

     Using the 'VS <version> <platform> <type> Command Prompt' menu entry:
       where version is the Visual Studio version, platform is e.g. x64
       and type Native of Cross platform build.  This type of command prompt
       may not exist in all Visual Studio versions.

       See also:
         https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx

Once you are in the console, go to the winbuild directory in the Curl
sources:
    cd curl-src\winbuild

Then you can call nmake /f Makefile.vc with the desired options (see below).
The builds will be in the top src directory, builds\ directory, in
a directory named using the options given to the nmake call.

nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=<static or dll> <options>

where <options> is one or many of:
  VC=<6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15>    - VC versions
  WITH_DEVEL=<path>              - Paths for the development files (SSL, zlib, etc.)
                                   Defaults to sibbling directory deps: ../deps
                                   Libraries can be fetched at https://windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/deps/
                                   Uncompress them into the deps folder.
  WITH_SSL=<dll or static>       - Enable OpenSSL support, DLL or static
  WITH_NGHTTP2=<dll or static>   - Enable HTTP/2 support, DLL or static
  WITH_MBEDTLS=<dll or static>   - Enable mbedTLS support, DLL or static
  WITH_CARES=<dll or static>     - Enable c-ares support, DLL or static
  WITH_ZLIB=<dll or static>      - Enable zlib support, DLL or static
  WITH_SSH2=<dll or static>      - Enable libSSH2 support, DLL or static
  WITH_PREFIX=<dir>              - Where to install the build
  ENABLE_SSPI=<yes or no>        - Enable SSPI support, defaults to yes
  ENABLE_IPV6=<yes or no>        - Enable IPv6, defaults to yes
  ENABLE_IDN=<yes or no>         - Enable use of Windows IDN APIs, defaults to yes
                                   Requires Windows Vista or later
  ENABLE_WINSSL=<yes or no>      - Enable native Windows SSL support, defaults to yes
  GEN_PDB=<yes or no>            - Generate Program Database (debug symbols for release build)
  DEBUG=<yes or no>              - Debug builds
  MACHINE=<x86 or x64>           - Target architecture (default is x86)
  CARES_PATH=<path to cares>     - Custom path for c-ares
  MBEDTLS_PATH=<path to mbedTLS> - Custom path for mbedTLS
  NGHTTP2_PATH=<path to HTTP/2>  - Custom path for nghttp2
  SSH2_PATH=<path to libSSH2>    - Custom path for libSSH2
  SSL_PATH=<path to OpenSSL>     - Custom path for OpenSSL
  ZLIB_PATH=<path to zlib>       - Custom path for zlib


Static linking of Microsoft's C RunTime (CRT):
==============================================
If you are using mode=static nmake will create and link to the static build of
libcurl but *not* the static CRT. If you must you can force nmake to link in
the static CRT by passing RTLIBCFG=static. Typically you shouldn't use that
option, and nmake will default to the DLL CRT. RTLIBCFG is rarely used and
therefore rarely tested. When passing RTLIBCFG for a configuration that was
already built but not with that option, or if the option was specified
differently, you must destroy the build directory containing the configuration
so that nmake can build it from scratch.

Building your own application with a static libcurl
===================================================
When building an application that uses the static libcurl library on Windows,
you must define CURL_STATICLIB. Otherwise the linker will look for dynamic
import symbols.

Legacy Windows and SSL
======================
When you build curl using the build files in this directory the default SSL
backend will be WinSSL (Windows SSPI, more specifically Schannel), the native
SSL library that comes with the Windows OS. WinSSL in Windows <= XP is not able
to connect to servers that no longer support the legacy handshakes and
algorithms used by those versions. If you will be using curl in one of those
earlier versions of Windows you should choose another SSL backend like OpenSSL.
```